# Push Header half way in

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to fix only a portion of my header to the top of my page, but can’t seem to find a solution. It’s either all or nothing.
What I’m trying to achieve is when scrolling content on the page to hide the header partially, and stop at the navigation menu. Content would continue to scroll, but nav is fixed to the top.

Thanks for any help or ideas.

Comment: Any code/examples/pictures that you'd like to share?

Comment: Without an example, it is impossible to help. Please provide code and/or a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I apologize. I wasn't able to add a picture, because it was the first time for me to post a question.

Comment: The code below pretty much sums up, what i needed to accomplish. I cam across this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/68eXM/3/) that would work better for me.
But, there might be even a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you don't use `position: fixed` only in the elements you want fixed. Like this:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5ecjr/)

Comment: Thank you, this is great. But my plan was slightly different. something more like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/68eXM/3/)